# Lose Focus when clicking actionbar button

Tags: android, focus

I have implemented a listener : onFocusChanged to insert values in db when a edittext lose focus.

The thing is when I click the Send button (in action bar), it first do the action, and then it triggers a last onFocusChanged.

It should first lose the focus, and then execute the action?
Can anybody explain me that?

The solution should be giving focus to another button that is not edittext, but I just have a actionbar button, and it seems difficult giving it the focus.

Any suggestion will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that tapping the Send button isn't changing the focus at all (it is probably a nonfocusable view).  What does your send operation do?  Is there something at the end of Send which might be setting focus to some other view?

Comment: I sync my data to an external MySQL DB.
Yes, you're right. At the end of the sync, I open a dialog, when closing the dialog, it calls finish(), and then I guess it triggers onFocusChange. But I can't find a solution to that problem, because I don't have any focusable views (Just actionbar items)....